# How to pass an integer series as argument to a python function?

Tags: python, function

Is there a way to execute the following statement in a more concise way in python?

instead of

```
a, b, c, d = f(1), f(2), f(3), f(4)
```

this:

```
a, b, c, d = some_way(f(x))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list comprehension like this

```
a, b, c, d = [f(i) for i in xrange(1, 5)]
```

Or using `map` function, like this

```
a, b, c, d = map(f, xrange(1, 5))
```

In both the cases,

```
print a, b, c, d
```

will print

```
1 4 9 16
```

**Edit:**

As mentioned in the comments section, here is the curried version

```
def curry_function(function, first, second):
    return lambda third: function(first, second, third)

f = curry_function(f, "dummy1", "dummy2")
```

And then you can use the code shown above. Instead of writing our own version of currying function, we can use [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) like this

```
from functools import partial
f = partial(f, "dummy1", "dummy2")
```

Comment: isnt there some sort of circular reference in `partial` method?

Comment: @alwbtc Nope, it just replaces the old function with the new function, which remembers the old function and passes `dummy1`, `dummy2` and the new parameter passed by the `map` function, the remembered old function. Pretty cool, huh? :)

Comment: right, cool. Cooler thing is that people on SO know so many things

Comment: @alwbtc I also learnt from SO only. Now in giving back mode :)

Answer (score 4):

You can try [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> def f(x): return x*x
... 
>>> a,b,c,d = map(f, (1,2,3,4))
>>> 
>>> a
1
>>> b
4
>>> c
9
>>> d
16
```

If your function arguments will always be consecutive, then you can also do:

```
>>> a,b,c,d = map(f, range(1,5))
```

Comment: @thefourtheye I was assuming the OP's values wouldn't always be consecutive, but if they are then yes.

Comment: What if the original statement is `a,b,c,d = f(some_arg, other_arg, 1), f(some_arg, other_arg, 2), f(some_arg, other_arg, 3), f(some_arg, other_arg, 1)` ? How to use `map` then?

Comment: @alwbtc Will `some_arg` and `other_arg` be the same for all the cases?

Answer (score 0):

Just an additional comment that requires some code... in your case where you want to supply arguments, if you use a list comprehension, you don't need the curry function:

```
# f(arg1, arg2, index)

a,b,c,d = [f(arg1, arg2, x) for x in range(1,5)]
```

List comprehensions are mostly equivalent in use to map, but this is one way in which they are superior.